# Using FireBase uid everywhere in code - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use the logged in users' uid anywhere in my code when I need it but I can't find a way how to. I'm able to log in, log out, update records etc. but if I want to use the uid on another dart file I'm not able to do so.

preferably I would like to add the uid in my constants file so that I can easily access it anywhere I need.

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 String uid = '';

auth.currentUser().then((val){
  setState(() {
  this.uid= val.uid; 
   print("UID: $uid");
  });
}).catchError((e){
print("error:$e");
});
```

Use `currentUser()` method of FirebaseAuth ([firebase_auth_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth)) class in initState(). it will give you current user uid.